# NodeJS event equivalent of thread local variables?

Tags: node.js

I'm experiment with the design of a framework but I'm new to NodeJS and its implementation of event based programming. In other environments I would use thread local variables for what I'm trying to do, is there something equivalent in NodeJS?

Obviously in NodeJS you rarely use threads, but events. What I'm searching for is a global variable that once something set it, will continue to have that value as callbacks are called from the original one that set, but not from others. Does that make sense?

What I'm trying to do is design a library/framework, so, I don't have any code at the moment, but for example, imagine there's a function like this:

```
    async function doSomething() {
       await connect()
       await doSomethingElse()
       await doSomethingElseAgain()
    }
```

I want `connect()` to store the connection on a *thread local* variable, so that `doSomethingElse()` and `doSomethingElseAgain()` use that same connection, even when there are two *threads* of `doSomething()` running (but I know they are not threads, but events running one after another from both executions of `doSomething()`).

I don't want to pass any parameters from `connect()` to other functions. I know how to do that already, but breaks the design I'm trying to come up with.

Comment: You would typically use local variables in a closure that would be accessible inside that closure only (where the event handlers are).  For more specific information on how to do this, please show your actual nodejs code.

Comment: @jfriend00: I know how closures work, but I don't want the user of my library/framework to be passing local variables around, that's what I'm trying to avoid. There's no code at the moment, but I can mock something up if this helps.

Comment: @jfriend00: there, I added some code.

Comment: Because of the event-driven, asynchronous nature of Javascript and how it runs all your code in one thread (except for WorkerThreads which is a different conversation entirely), the concept of thread locals doesn't really apply here.  All your code runs in the same thread anyway so even if there were thread locals, they wouldn't help you.  That's why you use closures and local variables or make the functions be methods of a common object and store the common data in that object or pass along a context object.

Comment: @jfriend00: that's not the only way. There's cls-hooked and async hooks, that don't depend on local variables.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure as I'm still exploring, but I believe I have found the solution and it's the package named [cls-hooked](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cls-hooked). I'll post more if I find more one way or another.

Comment: Just keep in mind that is an experimental feature and there is no guarantee that the current design or API stays forever.